# Excel data validation using Excel js

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, exceljs

I need help with cell validation. I have the min and max value. I have already stopped users to enter special characters in a cell. However, in testing I found that users can enter % in a cell and excel is not prompting the user for the invalid character.

I am using Excel.js which creates templates. In data validation, I have selected custom and my formula is =AND(M4>=0,M4<=100).

How can I create this formula? Only a number should be allowed, rest all result in an error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else needs it.

formulae: ['=AND(A5>=0,A5<=100,CELL("format", A5)<>"P0")']